# Recursive methods which exclude each other?

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am trying to write a method that calculates the sum of odd integers between 1 and a given positive integer n, without using anything else than if statements (sheesh!). It worked out just fine until I decided to also create a method that would ask recursively for the number until it was positive and use it to get n.

Now my program outputs the correct results until I enter a negative number. It then asks for a postive one until I enter one and it outputs 0, the value I initialised the variable val with.

I'm not sure where the logic error is. Could you please take a look? I'm sure it's something obvious, but I guess I have just reached the end of my wits today. Thanks!

```
package oddsum;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Oddsum {
        public static int oddSum(int n){
         int val=0;
         if(n>1){

            if(n%2==0){
                val=n+oddSum(n-1);

            }else{
                val=oddSum(n-1);

            }
        }
        return val;
        } 
        public static int request(int n){
            Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Give me a positive integer: ");
            n=in.nextInt();
                if (n<0){
                    System.out.println("I said positive! ");
                    request(n);
                }
            return n;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int val=0;
        int n=request(val);
        System.out.println(oddSum(n));  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove input parameter from your request() method. Because your negative input is carried out through the recursive call.

```
public class Oddsum {
    public static int oddSum(int n) {
        int val = 0;
        if (n > 1) {

            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                val = n + oddSum(n - 1);

            } else {
                val = oddSum(n - 1);

            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static int request() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give me a positive integer: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("I said positive! ");
            return request();
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = request();
        System.out.println(oddSum(n));
    }

}
```

Output;

[image: Odd sum]

Comment: I did, the code looks much better now, but the result is still zero if I input a negative number before I imput a positive one. I don't think that was the mistake.

Comment: I tested it and got the correct result. Let me send you whole code.

Comment: Haha, found the bug. I needed to return the request() when I called it recursively after the if(n<0), but I didn't. So it never got out a working variable if n<0 . Thanks a lot for the working code! :)